# HTTP Status 404 - /BilalWebtier/WEB-INF/jsp/loginParam.jsp

Tags: java, sql, jsp, jstl

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginDataAccess
 */
public class LoginDataAccess extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public LoginDataAccess() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        Principal p = request.getUserPrincipal();
        if(request.isUserInRole("user")){
            session.setAttribute("isUser", true);
        }
        String username = p.getName();
        System.out.println(username);
        String query = "SELECT user_name FROM tomcat_users WHERE user_name = '"+username+"'";
        System.out.println(query);
        /*
         * This next section deals with getting the Data Source from the context.
         */
        InitialContext context;
        DataSource dataSource = null;
        try {
            context = new InitialContext();
            //This is a bit of JNDI - we don't need to know how this works, just that it does.
            dataSource = (DataSource)context.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/connection");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Connection connection;
        ResultSet rset = null;
        try {
            connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while(rset.next()){
                session.setAttribute("user_name", rset.getString("user_name"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("GETS JUST BEFORE LOGIN PARAM");
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/loginParam.jsp");
        System.out.println("GETS JUST after LOGIN PARAM");
        rd.forward(request, response);

    }

}
```

form html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <p>
            This is the login page...
        </p>
        <form method="POST" action="j_security_check">
            <label>Username:<input type="text" name="j_username" /></label><br />
            <label>Password:<input type="password" name="j_password" /></label><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Login!">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

login param file where error seems to be occurring .

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This is a protected page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>You are viewing a protected page!</h1>
        <p>Your UserName is ${user_name}</p>
        <c:if test="${sessionScope.isUser}">

            <h2>You are a user!</h2>
        </c:if>

    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to retrieve login authentication. My result should provide with populating login param file with message user name is "". Instead it is providing me with following error.

```
HTTP Status 404 - /BilalWebtier/WEB-INF/jsp/loginParam.jsp
```

Type: Status report

message `/BilalWebtier/WEB-INF/jsp/loginParam.jsp`

Description: The requested resource is not available.

could you please help ?

Comment: Well...where is that file?

Comment: that file is stored in webcontent folder. i've pasted the content of that file above

Comment: your legend, that dod